# Confused about angular and rails routing together

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I'm trying to integrate AngularJS into part of my app where I have anything under the url `/events/something` be taken care of by angular routing. However, I've been following Angular's tutorial and [this](http://angular-rails.com/find_and_browse.html) except I can't seem to get the view to render. I think I'm doing something wrong in my routing but I can't seem to figure it out. Can anyone help me out?

Sample link: `http://localhost:3000/events/events1`

Rails route:

```
get '/events/:id' => 'event#event'
```

Angular Code:

```
var app = angular.module('eventsApp', ['ngRoute', 'templates']);

app.config(['$routeProvider',
    function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('events/:id', {
            templateUrl: 'eventTemp.html',
            controller: 'EventsCtrl'
        });
    }
]);
app.controller('EventsCtrl', function($scope, $http){
    console.log('yo!'); //this is never logging
});
```

outer template:

```
<div class = "event" ng-app="eventsApp">
    <div ng-view></div>
</div>
```

eventTemp.html

```
<h1>Text</h1>
```

I'm using the `angular-rails-templates` gem and I have all my templates in `app/assets/javascripts/templates`. This is what `application.js` looks like:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require_tree .
//= require angular-rails-templates
//= require_tree ./templates
//= require turbolinks
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I played around with it and it turns out something is wrong with

```
$routeProvider.when('events/:id'
```

When I change the method to this:

```
var app = angular.module('eventsApp', ['ngRoute', 'templates']);

app.config([
  '$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {      
    $routeProvider.
     when('/', {
        templateUrl: '../templates/eventTemp2.html',
        controller: 'EventsCtrl2'
     }).
     otherwise({
        templateUrl: '../templates/eventTemp.html',
        controller: 'EventsCtrl'
     });
  }
]);
app.controller('EventsCtrl', function($scope, $http){
    console.log('yo!');
});

app.controller('EventsCtrl2', function($scope, $http) {
    console.log('yo2');
});
```

`EventsCtrl2` and `eventTemp.html2` get rendered.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem once, and the solution is this - use:

```
$routeProvider('/events/:id')
```

instead of

```
$routeProvider('events/:id')
```

Apparently, angular requires is routing paths to start with `/`.

Comment: Yeah I figured that out after trying a ton of different combinations for the URL matching... 
thanks anyhow!

Answer (score 0):

Is your Angular app in the same directory as the template? If not, templateUrl needs to be the correct path.

```
templates/eventTemp.html
```